How to build and consume an Angular 18 library
The project I'm working on needs to split some components into a shared library. I'm using Angular 18 with standalone components. I've found a lot of answers / articles for these issues online, but none seem to actually answer my question or fix the build issues.
I'm starting this experiment with new, mostly empty Angular projects just to see if I can get it to work, before doing this with the actual project code.
Ideally this will end up living in a private NPM repo or maybe git somewhere.
Here's what I've done (names aren't great, sorry):
Create a new folder called "test", then cd into it.
cd test
Create lib workspace.
ng new lib
cd lib
Create library project.
ng g library test-lib
The generate command adds an example component, so I'll use that to test with. I'm not adding anything else to the library at this time.
Build library.
ng build
Pack library.
cd projects/test-lib
npm pack
This creates test-lib-0.0.1.tgz.
Now, back in the parent test directory, add another test project to consume the lib.
ng new test
cd test
Install local library module:
npm i {path-before-test}/test/lib/projects/test-lib -S
(I've also tried {pah-before-test}/test/lib/projects/test-lib/test-lib-0.0.1.tgz directly)
I can see that the files from the packed library are in node_modules.
Now, in app.component.ts of this test project, try to import the component from the lib.
import { TestLibComponent } from 'test-lib';
This results in a linting error on test-lib: Cannot find module 'test-lib' or its corresponding type declarations.
I've tried some hacky things with tsconfig.js and tsconfig.app.js as found in other answers for similar issues, but one, they don't seem like things I really want to change, like changing the target of the ts module. Also tried adding paths to the folders in node_modules and setting baseUrl to "./". These don't solve the problem.
I've also tried importing the component directly from test-lib/src/public-api. This removes the linting error, but results in an actual compile error: File 'node_modules\test-lib\src\public-api.ts' is missing from the TypeScript compilation.
What am I doing wrong?

Two issues here. First, ng build only builds the application, not the library. Basically you have two projects in the repository, the application and the library. And because you created the application first, it is the default project, if no project specified. To build the library, you need to specify the project by running ng build test-lib.
Second, you are packing the source files, not the built library. Instead of packing projects/test-lib, you need to pack dist/test-lib.
Further reading: https://angular.dev/tools/libraries/creating-libraries#publishing-your-library

This is something I keep seeing in other articles, and I haven't gotten a clear answer on. When I run ng build in the library, it outputs to dist, but there is no package.json file, so npm pack doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions for this?

@jmarkyston it's because you are building the application and not the library. To build the library, you need to run ng build test-lib. Updated my answer.

I see now. Thank you so much for your help!

Change your cd projects/test-lib -> cd <path-to-your-dist>/test-lib from there run npm pack.
After that from your new angular app run :
npm install ../<path-to-your-dist>/test-lib-0.0.1.tgz
Then make sure to update tsconfig.json in the new app to include test-lib path :
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "test-lib": ["../node_modules/test-lib"]
    }
  },
}

and update your tsconfig.app.json to like below:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "test",
    "**/*spec.ts"
  ]
}

Now you can refer to your library in the new angular app that you created.

This is something I keep seeing in other articles, and I haven't gotten a clear answer on. When I run ng build in the library, it outputs to dist, but there is no package.json file, so npm pack doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions for this?
